# Maven build fails in Jenkins with Exception in provider: org/apache/velocity/context/Context

Tags: maven, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, testng

3/31/2017
I am new to Maven/Jenkins.

I have a Maven project following is the directory structure:

```
\TestMavenJenkinsProject\src\main\java\PC_Home_ThisWeeksSpecials_HeaderText_Test.java
\TestMavenJenkinsProject\pom.xml
\TestMavenJenkinsProject\testng.xml
```

The build failed in Jenkins with error details below:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-test) on project TestMavenJenkinsProject: Exception in provider: org/apache/velocity/context/Context: org.apache.velocity.context.Context -> [Help 1]

The pom.xml file has an entry for velocity dependency as below:

```
  <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
            <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
    </dependency>
```

### Your thoughts are appreciated.  Thank you.

4/3/2017 Status Update
The issue was resolved when I added a dependency for junit and installed Maven related plug-ins, and installed as a windows service.  It is nice to see the testNG report when Jenkins is complete a build.

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: can you replace the above dependency to below and try again

Comment: `<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.velocity/velocity -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
    <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.0.redhat-5</version>
</dependency>
`

Comment: Hello  AmitK,I replaced the dependency per your suggestion, but I got a different error. >[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project TestMavenJenkinsProject: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.cobornsdelivers:TestMavenJenkinsProject:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find org.apache.velocity:velocity:jar:1.7.0.redhat-5 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1].  Thank you for your thoughts.